# Receiving 404 from node when accessing Angular route

Tags: node.js, angular, angular8

I am developing Angular 8 application and published first version of it.
When I am using buttons in application to switch between views, all works fine.
If I try to access directly to one of URL's (example: http://somedomain/someview) I receive 404
from Node. I do understand why this is happening and referred to few posts but nothing seems to work.

Comment: any authguard set for that route?

Comment: On some of them

Comment: so can you please check it that authguard or specific condition on route for stop access that url.

Comment: but all routes not working. Also, I have 404 handler in angular application. I receive 404 from node since it does not recognize the path. I need somehow to update node js rule for re-routing

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind your application link to change, you can considered using angular's location hash strategy.
You can enable it by simply adding the useHash option in the module which you import RouterModule:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})
```

This way, the routes will be correctly passed to angular instead of the node server trying to process it.
Your app link will change to look like this: http://somedomain/#someview

Comment: Thanks, but actually I am trying hard to avoid this solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set node to always service index.html in case of a route that doesn't exist.

How to do this exactly depends on how your server application is configured.

Let's assume you are using `express`, and your static files are in the directory `public`. In this case, you probably service the static files with `express.static`:

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

You'd need to add a catch-all route handler at the end of your other handlers which serves `public/index.html`:

```js
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html'))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a **.htaccess file** in your deployed project folder,
add below content in **.htaccess** file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

Hope this helps.